# Free orders with CartThrob 2.6?

Tags: cartthrob

Is the "Free Order" discount working for anyone else in CartThrob 2.6 and EE 2.8.1? It seems to be completely broken - the cart still uses the undiscounted amount as the total. It looks like CT recalculates the total from scratch if it sees that the total is <= $0 in the total() function in cartthrob/core/Cartthrob_cart.php, but I can't figure out how to make it stop without breaking calculations for normal (non-discounted) orders.

Answer (score 0):

I found a commented out line at the end of cartthrob/plugins/discount/Cartthrob_discount_free_order.php. I uncommented that line and commented out the replacement line (`return 0;`). This seems to work, but I assume there was a reason it was commented out in the first place, so I'm not sure if I've broken anything else....

Comment: Did you ever find the correct fix for this? I'm experiencing this same issue, but with EE 2.9.2 and CartThrob 2.6.

Comment: No, not really....

Comment: FWIW: in CartThrob 2.7, I had to change the last line of plugins/discount/Cartthrob_discount_free_order.php to: `return $this->core->cart->subtotal_with_tax() + $this->core->cart->shipping();` to make it work.